# Qt5 development libraries for Debian

Tags: debian, qt, qt5

So, I'm trying to compile VLC myself, as I noticed the Debian package refused to show VA-API support in the settings (and according to intel_gpu_top isn't using it). And while the flatpak version does include it, it still can only use XWayland and thus is blurry when using fractional scaling (and seems to be impossible to be forced to use Wayland). Compiling 3.0.20 failed due to some ominous reasons, so I gave the 4.0 development release a go. But while it seemed that the 3.0.20 build was eventually able to find the needed Qt5 libraries, the 4.0 branch doesn't. It ends with

```
checking for Qt5Core >= 5.11.0 Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5Quick Qt5QuickWidgets Qt5QuickControls2 Qt5Svg... no
configure: error: Package 'Qt5Quick', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'Qt5QuickWidgets', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'Qt5QuickControls2', required by 'virtual:world', not found. If you want to build VLC without GUI, pass --disable-qt.
```

Is there any other package besides qtbase5-dev that needs to be installed for these? From apt-file I can deduce that the packages qtdeclarative5-dev, libqt5svg5-dev, qtbase5-gles-dev, qtquickcontrols2-5-dev and libqt5svg5-dev. But installing them isn't an option as that would uninstall programs like kalzium, kdenlive or qtqr.

I'm on Debian Testing btw.